# PHP run fopen as admin, not _www

Tags: php, installation, exec, fopen, sudo

This MUST be a duplicate, but I can't find an answer...

I'm writing an php web install script. I want php to write a file that will subsequently be unwritable. Isn't there some way to sudo fopen?

Obviously the _www credentials will not begin with write access to the directory, nor will they end with it. I'm thinking the installing user, who will have write access will pass their credentials to the script which will handle the rest.

Comment: When you say 'admin' what do you mean ? What platform are you running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sudo from within PHP.  If you want to run something as root, you'd have to add the Apache user `www` to the sudoers file, which is probably not a good idea.  And if you're writing an install script that others will run, it won't even be an option.

That being the case, you can't create files in a directory that you don't have access to at the beginning, though you can use `chmod()` to make the file read-only after you've finished writing it.  This won't mean that another script run by Apache couldn't later use the same function to re-add the write attributes.

Your best bet is to create empty versions of the files that you need to write to.  Have your script check for write access at the beginning, and if it's not present, tell the user what they need to do to give you write access.  Once that's completed, they can proceed.  Your script will write the files, then tell the user what they need to do to remove write access.  Your script will check that that has happened, and will not allow the user to continue to the next step until they've successfully removed write access.

Answer (score 1):

What most do is provide empty files and let installers chmod them for writing.

This will let the users maintain the user who provided the file initially.

Bonus is that you could probably write more secure applications instead of having your application being able to write the server.